# Could I damage my MoBo from using 2 monitors one plugged on GPU and one plugged on MoBo?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

This question may seem odd but my previous MoBo died really early and I never knew if that was the cause of it's death. I was plugging one monitor on the MoBo and one on the GPU. Weird symptoms appeared and different graphical glitches on each monitor occurred when it was crashing. So now I have my new MoBo, it is safe to do that ? I would prefer plugging my two monitors on my GPU but I would have to buy an adapter. My first monitor is plugged using HDMI and my second one could be plugged to my MoBo using VGA.

So, should I bother buying this new adapter ? Could there be a link between my previous MoBo failure and this usage ?

Comment: Are you asking if its safe to connect 2 monitors to your Motherboard?

Comment: @Ramhound One on the MoBo, one on the GPU. Will clarify in the question

Comment: *Could there be a link between my previous MoBo failure and this usage ?* - **NO** *So, should I bother buying this new adapter?* - The only person who can answer this question is yourself.  *it is safe to do that?* - Of course it is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A motherboard can die in many ways, one can actually be a manufacturer error and means there's nothing you can do. For this reason warranty exists.

As to answer your question, can a motherboard die if one monitor is hooked up to the GPU while the other one is hooked up to the motherboard port?

Very unlikely. I use this setup for my clients many times and never seen a failure. So unless something is really weird, it should not happen. And if it does happen it is likely that it would have happened if only that monitor was hooked up to the motherboard and no extra monitor was connected.

So technically speaking, you should not need an adapter.